# NetSuite- Advanced PDF Template, How Can I get Each Item's Component Information Through Salesorder Record

Tags: oracle, netsuite

I am trying to customize a pdf template so I can print my own Picking Ticket. I can get all salesorder's information/data by use ${record.[fieldId]}, and I can also get all items' general/header information in the current salesorder's record using ${item.[fieldId]}. However, can anyone tell me how to get each item's components list through "item.[...]"

I tried to use "item.member", where member is the components list of each item, and it always said "item.member" is not a sequence or list.

Any idea? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print this information with NetSuite's new Saved Search printing feature that was released in 2017.1.  Make an item saved search with Member Item being one of the results.  Then create a template from the saved search with the "New Template" button.  Use this tag somewhere in your document:

${result.memberitem}

See SuiteAnswers article "Advanced Templates for Printing Saved Search Results" if you want to learn how to print all results on one page.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `record` - just use `${item.[field]}`

You'll notice in the source code at the start of the item list table it has `<#list record.item as item>`

Comment: But, inside EACH ITEM, there is a list of components.
I use <#list record.item as item><#/list> to print some general information about each item. I also want to get their components information. Inside the <#list record.item as item><#/list> tag, I tried to use <#list item.member as component><#/list> to get the components list, which always shows error because item.member is not a sequence or list.

Comment: I looked at the Item's XML page. It clearly shows that the components list is called "member", like "<machine name="member" type="edit".....>"